# List of cases in Go that allow omitting an optional second returned value

Tags: go

When calling functions or methods with multiple return values, the caller, if unpacking any return values, must unpack them ALL.

```
f, err := os.Open("filename")
```

The `err` variable must be either declared or ignored with the blank identifier `_`, but it cannot be omitted.

However, there are some operations built into the language, which allow one to omit the optional second return value.

Is there a more or less formal list of situations where an operation with a data structure or a function call returns a second value that is optional and can be ignored by only receiving the first return value? For example:

```
m := make(map[string]int)
v, ok := m["hello"]
```

The `ok` variable is entirely optional and can be omitted.

```
v := m["hello"]
```

Likewise, with channels:

`v, ok := <-ch`

or

`v := <-ch`

Are there any other cases of that behavior beyond the two above?

Comment: Those are the only  cases I can think of but read the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions with optional values when used in an assignment or initialization are:  [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), [map index](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [channel receive](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator).

The specification does not have a formal list of these expressions, but the expressions are all described in the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).